# How to loop through files named in a text file? Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

- Windows Server 2012 cmd.exe box
- I need to make a batch file, call it `get.bat`, to process all directories listed in `dlist.txt` which is in the same dir as `get.bat`. Directory names are one per line in dlist.txt. dlist.txt was created with `dir /b DIV_* > dlist.txt`. These DIV_ files are actually subdirectories to the dir where my batch file is run.
- I cannot use a filespec in the FOR command because I need to edit `dlist.txt` by hand after creating it. I don't want to process all dirs like `DIV_*`, just some of them.
- Creating `dlist.txt` with `dir /w DIV_* > dlist.txt` means all directory names have [] around them and I cannot use that.
- There is one parameter to `get.bat` which is a base filename to contain all results form the `fromxsf` command. The .txt extension will be added by the batch file.
- I need to do multiple commands to each dir in `dlist.txt`, some of which are setting a temp filename called %tempoutfile% then used in `fromxsf`.
- I've read several pages I found on Google, including some from Superuser but the examples that might work for cmd.exe did not work for me. Maybe Windows 2012 Server is too old? I cannot change that, I have to work with what I've got.
- `fromxsf` that processes each directory in `dlist.txt` requires the directory as one parameter after the `-cd` and a temporary output file as another parameter which is %tempoutfile%.
- We don't appear to have powershell or at least there is no path set to it.

Here's what I've tried using a FOR loop:

```
set destdir=c:\tempdir
set outfile=%destdir%\%1.txt
FOR /F %%f in ('type dlist.txt') DO (
    echo "--------------------"

    echo Basedir=%%f should be directory
    set tempoutfile=../%%f.txt
    echo outfile=%destdir%\%outfile%
    echo tempoutfile=%tempoutfile%
    echo Processing dir %%f, to tempfile %tempfile%
    pause
    rem Below is the command to process the dir name in %%f to make a temp file in %tempoutfile%
    fromxsf %tempoutfile% -cd %%f +m -nbs -Rep -nofrills

    if exist "%destdir%" (
        echo " " >> %outfile%
        echo "{DIVNAME=%i}" >> %outfile%
        rem Append %tempoutfile% to %outfile%.
        type %tempoutfile% >> %outfile%
        del %tempoutfile%
    )
)
```

For the above the value of %%f is always the first line of dlist.txt. That is not what I want.

What I'm doing in the loop is outputting the processed contents of the directory into a temp file in %tempfile%, and then concatenating the contents of %tempfile% to %destdir%\%outfile%. `mycommand` requires the input directory %%f as a command line arg. I just can't redirect STDOUT and append the output to %destdir%\%outfile%.

Some alternate FOR loops I've tried:

- `FOR %%f in (dlist.txt) DO (`. For this case `%%f` is always the second dir name in `dlist.txt` and never changes.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

---

EDIT: Thanks. I figured it out using delayed expansion and another post I found using Google. The core of the loop is this, with filenames contained in the text file `dlist.txt` one filename per line. My problem was the missing `"tokens=*"` option. Also the !variable! notation must be used EVERY time in the loop. The loop below also has echo statements to show the values of variables.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set outfile=c:\temp\tempout.txt
del %outfile%
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in (dlist.txt) DO (
    echo.
    echo --------------------
    set indir=%%f
    echo Basediv indir=!indir!
    echo Processing division !indir!

    echo. >> %outfile%
    echo {DIVNAME=!indir!} >> %outfile%
    pause
    fromxsf %outfile% -cd !indir! +m -nbs -Rep -nofrills -a
)
```

### Key issues in my loop

1. Use the `%%f` variable only once per loop and assign it to `indir`. From thereafter use the `!indir!` variable.
2. I removed the use of `%tempoutfile%` because the `fromxsf` command allows me to append output from itself (using -a) IF the file exists, which it does in this case.

Comment: 1. Where does %tempoutfile% get assigned a value? 2. Regarding setting/expanding variables inside a FOR or IF multiline block, you need to study "delayed expansion" and the exclamation-mark `!variable!` notation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: there was a typo. %tempoutfile% is assigned near the top of the FOR loop.

Comment: Fix the delayed expansion thing.